Module '"expo-camera"' has no exported member 'CameraView'.ts(2305)
I just installed expo-camera and following their sample code I am getting the error
Module '"expo-camera"' has no exported member 'CameraView'.ts(2305)

The same happens for useCameraPermissions. Everything looks right. The version is 14.1.3.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Turns out the way to install expo-camera is the same for the legacy version and the new one. You run npx expo install expo-camera and in my case it was installing the legacy version. I ran npx expo install expo-camera@latest and got the new module.
